# Is there a simple way to configure and enable live TypeScript checking in Windows 10 VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code on Windows 10 and tried to follow instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript)

As a result I have Node and NPM also installed correctly. I think there is a gap in setup instructions as it goes from NPM installing TypeScript to using it without any configuration details in between. Once I have installed TypeScript in Windows, how do I make

my aim is to have VS Code check and highlight errors as I type like Intellisense for the TypeScript language. e.g. this should show up some issues and highlighting, but isn't.

```
let message: string = "hello world";
console.log("message");

type MyType = {
    value: String;
}

let myvar: MyType = {
    value: undefined
}

type MyFunction = () => void;
function myFunction<MyFunction>(value) {
    value++;
}
```

I love VS Code but I've never got on too well with Microsoft documentation. I guess I'm looking for some up-to-date online instruction on how to configure this properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called ESLint you need to install and then you can run `npm i eslint` and create a `eslint.json` file for the rules you want to follow.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint